# mongodb bulk remove and insert

Tags: python, mongodb

i am learning  python with mongodb in torando

my data is

```
[
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5671350061be0b0a6454d68e"),
    "Pid" : "566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d",
    "EndDate" : "10-12-2015",
    "StartDate" : "5-12-2015",
    "Registration" : "TN 64 KS 7777",
    "Status" : "Booked"
     "Period": "12-2015"
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5671350061be0b0a6454d68f"),
    "Pid" : "566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d",
    "EndDate" : "20-12-2015",
    "StartDate" : "15-12-2015",
    "Registration" : "TN 64 KS 7777",
    "Status" : "NA"
    "Period": "12-2015"
  }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5671350061be0b0a6454d690"),
    "Pid" : "566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d",
    "EndDate" : "24-12-2015",
    "StartDate" : "21-12-2015",
    "Registration" : "TN 64 KS 7777",
    "Status" : "AOs"
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5671350061be0b0a6454d691"),
    "Pid" : "566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d",
    "EndDate" : "30-12-2015",
    "StartDate" : "25-12-2015",
    "Registration" : "TN 64 KS 7777",
    "Status" : "AOr"
    "Period": "12-2015"
 }
]
```

i have tried this code for bulk remove

```
 bulk = db.calendar.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
 bulk.find({"Period": p}).remove()
 bulk.execute()
```

i also need to insert another set of data which i earlier inserted as

```
db.calendar.insert(data)
```

which is stored in the db as

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5671350061be0b0a6454d68e"),
    "Pid" : "566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d",
    "EndDate" : "10-12-2015",
    "StartDate" : "5-12-2015",
    "Registration" : "TN 64 KS 7777",
    "Status" : "Booked"
 }
 {
    "Pid" : "566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d",
    "EndDate" : "10-12-2015",
    "StartDate" : "5-12-2015",
    "Registration" : "TN 64 KS 7777",
    "Status" : "Booked"
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5671350061be0b0a6454d690"),
    "Pid" : "566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d",
    "EndDate" : "10-12-2015",
    "StartDate" : "5-12-2015",
    "Registration" : "TN 64 KS 7777",
    "Status" : "Booked"
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5671350061be0b0a6454d691"),
    "Pid" : "566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d",
    "EndDate" : "10-12-2015",
    "StartDate" : "5-12-2015",
    "Registration" : "TN 64 KS 7777",
    "Status" : "Booked"
 }
```

And the first set of data

```
{"Pid" : "566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d",
 "EndDate" : "10-12-2015",
 "StartDate" : "5-12-2015",
 "Registration" : "TN 64 KS 7777",
 "Status" : "Booked"}
```

is stored repeatedly.

i would like to use `bulk` operation to solve this problem.

Can anyone tell me how to do it

I tried it by doing this

```
 p = "12-2015"

 bulk = db.calendar.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
 bulk.find({"Period": p}).remove()
 bulk.insert(data)
 bulk.execute()
```

but got error.

**Edit:**

I would like to use bulk because i have to access the same collection twice in a single connection.

Comment: What is `p`? why do you want to use "bulk" operations? Also please as you seem new here please take a [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

For bulk deletion, you don't need anything special. This should be fine:

```
db.calendar.remove({"Period": p})
```

Or if you have already fetched the records for an earlier use, you can do this:

```
records = db.calendar.find({"Period": p})
records.remove()
```

You can use [`insert_many`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) to insert the data in one query.

```
db.calendar.insert_many(data)
```

Comment: @EnriqueQuero I think both works. A cursor would also have a `remove` method. However, your one is more efficient. Updating the answer. Thanks for pointing out.